# Fulltext search slow SQL V12 Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, full-text-search

Fulltext search is finally supported in SQL Server V12 at MS Azure. It works as expected, but the first time you run a search it's immensely slow. In fact it times out quite often. The consecutive searches runs very fast, though. Seems that the fulltext engine is loaded into memory. Anybody experienced the same thing?

Comment: Same happening to me. 5-6 second lag on first search, then ultra-fast. If I wait a minute and try again, it is slow again on first search. Seems like something is loaded into memory and thrown out again after a short while

Answer (score 2):

This is expected as the FTS (word breaker) starts when needed.