# SQLAzure fulltext intermittent slow

Tags: full-text-search, azure-sql-database

I have a following query which uses fulltext indexes on SQLAzure database.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    {table} T
WHERE 
    CONTAINS(T.Column, @Search)
    OR EXISTS(
        SELECT NULL 
        FROM {anotherTable} AT 
        WHERE AT.Id = T.AnotherTableId AND CONTAINS(AT.Name, @Search))
```

The query runs very fast always if I run it from SQL Management Studio. But if I run it from the application it is as fast as from Management Studio, but sometimes it gets 10 times slower (and the next query is fast again).

What might cause this intermittent slowness?

I found one post which describes similar symptoms here: [Fulltext search slow SQL V12 Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30798694/fulltext-search-slow-sql-v12-azure) but has no certain result or recommendation.

Comment: Maybe it is the nature of the shared environment of Azure SQL Database? Sometimes the resources are busy.

Answer (score 0):

Full-text Search on Azure SQL DB is implemented in a way that it shares the resources between the SQL Engine and the Full-text Search process.

Every time a full-text search operation gets executed for the first time, the resources need to be allocated to the process and, as a result, it takes some time from the execution.

We are working to make sure this experience is as seamless as possible.

Thanks,
Luis

Comment: Thanks Luis for your answer. What can we do from our side to mitigate this as much as possible? Or just wait until it improves with further implementation from SQLAzure team?

Comment: One of the best practices would be to execute all FTS operations as sequentially to minimize the delay from the allocation of resources.

Comment: Yeah, but if I understand it correctly, the first FTS operation will be slow. How to mitigate this "first query" slowness?

Comment: There is no way to mitigate the slowness of that first query. The allocation of resources needs to happen on the service side.

Comment: Thanks. You said you are "working to make sure this experience is as seamless as possible" so is it somewhere logged to see your progress on it?

Comment: Not really. But we can discuss more about how we could solve these issues you're experiencing. Please email me at lbosq at microsoft.com - I would love to hear more about your use case. Thanks!

Comment: @LuisBosquez does the team fixed this issue with slow first full-text search ? We have first SQL statement on the table which has column related with full-text search. Quite often, the first simple request after the night to this table is very slow. It can happen couple of times during a day for random users. When we execute the same SQL statement in MSSMS, everything works pretty fast.